# Eigenvalues for Quaternion matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quaternions

We denote the real quaternion algebra by $\mathbb{H}.$ In [Zhang, Fuzhen. "Quaternions and matrices of quaternions." Linear algebra and its applications 251 (1997): 21-57.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82180866.pdf), I'm having some trouble following.

Example 5.1. Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\j&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then the left eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $i,$ whereas the right eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and all the quaternions in $[i]=\{gig^{-1}\mid g\in\mathbb{H},g\neq0\}.$

Theorem 5.4 (Brenner, 1951; Lee, 1949). Any $n\times n$ quaternion matrix $A$ has exactly $n$ (right) eigenvalues which are complex numbers with nonnegative imaginary parts.

Example 5.1 is probably the counterexample to Theorem 5.4 because $A$ has infinite right eigenvalues. I also see another example. For instance, the right eigenvalues of $$B=\begin{pmatrix}1-j+k&j+k\\1+i-j-k&i-j+k\end{pmatrix}$$ are $1$ and all the quaternions in $[i]$. I don't know if I misunderstood Theorem 5.4.

Also, I'm wondering why we do research first right eigenvalues and not left eigenvalues. I think left eigenvalues are closer to Linear algebra over fields. Thanks for all your support.

Comment: For $A$ to have left eigenvalue 1, you’d need an eigenvector (x,y) such that $yi=x$ and $xj=y$, which implies $yk=y$ and $k=1$, a contradiction. Are you sure you’ve got the definition of left eigenvalue written down correctly?

Comment: The matrix $jI_2$ doesn’t look like it has complex number eigenvalues…

Comment: Maybe they're talking about two different definitions.  It's well-known that polynomials over $\mathbb H$ can have infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb H$.  I could be forgetting something but I don't think (using the equation $Ax=\lambda x$ you can get any more than $n$ solutions because that refers to eigenvalues as scaling subspaces, and there isn't any way to have a transformation scale a subspace the same way with multiple values...

Comment: I don't recall having ever seen the idea of an eigenvalue of a quaternion matrix developed. On general principles I would think that multiplication by $A$ has to be $\Bbb{H}$-linear. Meaning that the eigenvalue will necessarily act from the opposite side of $A$ (the product is associative but not commutative). So I hazard a guess that $(x\ y)$ is a right eigenvector of $A$ if there exists a quaternion $\lambda$ such that
$$\lambda (x\ y)= (x\ y)A.$$
Similarly, the condition
$$\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr} \lambda = A\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}$$
would define a left eigenvector. Is this how it's done?

Comment: The point being that multiplication by $A$ of a column vector $\in\Bbb{H}^2$ from the left is a homomorphism of $\Bbb{H}$-modules only if $\Bbb{H}$ acts on $\Bbb{H}^2$ **from the right**. Similarly for multiplication of a row vector by $A$ from the right is a homomorphism of left $\Bbb{H}$-modules, so $\lambda$ needs to be on the left.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I’m well aware of the reasons for putting operators and scalars on opposite sides, but I don’t see the need to require the eigenvalue to act as a scalar that commutes with $A$.  It seems like it could equally well be the scalar operation on the same side as $A$ so that they are both linear transformations on the right. That is “A looks like a scalar transformation on an eigenspace”.  Maybe there is a reason I’m not seeing that breaks the tie? Of course, knowing the OPs definitions is the only way forward…

Comment: @rschwieb Ok. That's a possibility. That way we have an eigenspace (or an eigen submodule). I overlooked this way of thinking about it. Thanks.

Comment: @rschwieb Looks like the article has a typo. Examples 5.1. and 5.2. are duplicates of each other (albeit with different eigenvalues), and, as your calculation shows, the matrix $A4 does not have $1$ as an eigenvalue (it being real it doesn't matter which side it acts on).

Comment: Trần Nam Sơn, but what is the counterexample you see? Among the quaternions $gig^{-1}$ the quaternion $i$ is the only one that is also complex number and has a non-negative imaginary part. In other words, I now think (after a quick glance at the paper) that Theorem 5.4. uses the phrase *a complex number with a non-negative imaginary part* to single out a representative of each conjugacy class.

Comment: As in: the quaternion $a+bi+cj+dk$ is in the conjugacy class of $a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2}i$. The latter is a complex number with a non-negative imaginary part, and the only element of this conjugacy class with those properties.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same problem, the link was a little flaky for me.  I'm inserting a citation into the post now...